# Change the height of a row in UITableView causes strange glitch/blinking

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have the following code:

```
// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return yearsList.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if let aIndexPath = selectedIndexPath {
        if (aIndexPath != indexPath) {
            return kPauYearCellCollpasedHeight
        } else {
            let height : CGFloat = PauYearTableViewCell.buttonsContainerHeight(examsList)
            return height
        }
    } else {
        return kPauYearCellCollpasedHeight
    }
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("PauYearCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! PauYearTableViewCell

    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None
    cell.backgroundView = nil
    cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
    cell.yearLabel.text = yearsList[indexPath.row]
    cell.examsList = examsList
    cell.checkHeight(selectedIndexPath == indexPath)
    return cell
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    self.tableView.beginUpdates()
    if let theSelectedIndexPath = selectedIndexPath {
        if (indexPath == theSelectedIndexPath) {
            selectedIndexPath = nil
            self.tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.None)
        } else {
            let previousIndexPath = theSelectedIndexPath
            selectedIndexPath = indexPath
            self.tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([previousIndexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.None)
            self.tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([selectedIndexPath!], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.None)
        }
    } else {
        selectedIndexPath = indexPath
        self.tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([selectedIndexPath!], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.None)
    }
    self.tableView.endUpdates()
}
```

I use it in order to expand/collapse the selected UITableViewCell in order to show some buttons below the cell title.

But I can't make it work right. I have tried every solution I have found but when I tap on a cell, some cells of the UITableViewCell blinks for a moment causing a strange visual effect.

Here you can see a video reproducing the error:

https://youtu.be/cq0RBwEyFXI

If you can help my or point me on the right direction I will be very pleasure because I am starting to get frustated

Comment: Why do you set cell.backgroundView to nil?

Comment: wow!!!!!!!!!!! that's was the error!!! But I don't undestand why!
And if you can post your comment as an answer I will marked it.
Many thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you set cell.backgroundView to nil?